# Does Android App Bundle (AAB) have a single versionCode for all architectures?

Tags: android, continuous-integration, apk

We have just moved to using the Android AAB format for releasing. Originally our APKs were generated used the versionCode from the manifest and once uploaded into Google Play Console, each APK was given an architecture specific prefix. e.g. versionCode=45, Arm32=200045, x86_64=500045 etc.

We had to use the highest versionCode + 1 (e.g. 50046) from the current release as the versionCode in the android manifest to be able to load the AAB image into Google Play Console.

Once installed on different devices (architecture and bitness) the versionCode reported from the device is for the AAB (e.g. 500046).

Is it correct that there's only now a single versionCode for all auto-generated APKs?